# How to optimise this code to not be so chunky

Tags: python

Here is a calculator that takes 3 inputs, the group size, money contributed, and amount of product. My issue with it is the amount of unnecessary code and repetition i have done. Ive spent awhile trying to minimize it to get rid of the need to do every different group size manually but i seem to have a thought block when getting into the loops.

My question how to optimise this code to get rid of all the repetition. How do you use a while loop or any method to assign different variables every time the next person amount needs to be calculated.

Its limited too six because if i wanted to make it more thats just another chunk.

Thanks in adavance.

````
"\nHow many people are buying? MAX 6: "))

    
Gs = float(input("How many grams are you picking up?: "))
Ps = float(input("How much money is being paid?: "))
PPG = Ps / Gs
print ("Price per gram is:" ,"£",PPG,)


def MainCalc():
    if GroupNo == 6:
        P1 = int(input("How much £ is person 1 putting in: "))
        P2 = int(input("How much £ is person 2 putting in: "))
        P3 = int(input("How much £ is person 3 putting in: "))
        P4 = int(input("How much £ is person 4 putting in: "))
        P5 = int(input("How much £ is person 5 putting in: "))
        P6 = int(input("How much £ is person 6 putting in: "))
        P1_Gs = P1 / PPG  
        print("Person 1 should get",P1_Gs,)
        P2_Gs = P2 / PPG  
        print("Person 2 should get",P2_Gs,)
        P3_Gs = P3 / PPG  
        print("Person 3 should get",P3_Gs,)
        P4_Gs = P4 / PPG  
        print("Person 4 should get",P4_Gs,)
        P5_Gs = P5 / PPG  
        print("Person 5 should get",P5_Gs,)
        P6_Gs = P6 / PPG  
        print("Person 6 should get",P6_Gs,)
    elif GroupNo == 5:
        P1 = int(input("How much £ is person 1 putting in: "))
        P2 = int(input("How much £ is person 2 putting in: "))
        P3 = int(input("How much £ is person 3 putting in: "))
        P4 = int(input("How much £ is person 4 putting in: "))
        P5 = int(input("How much £ is person 5 putting in: "))
        P1_Gs = P1 / PPG  
        print("Person 1 should get",P1_Gs,)
        P2_Gs = P2 / PPG  
        print("Person 2 should get",P2_Gs,)
        P3_Gs = P3 / PPG  
        print("Person 3 should get",P3_Gs,)
        P4_Gs = P4 / PPG  
        print("Person 4 should get",P4_Gs,)
        P5_Gs = P5 / PPG  
        print("Person 5 should get",P5_Gs,)
    elif GroupNo == 4:
        P1 = int(input("How much £ is person 1 putting in: "))
        P2 = int(input("How much £ is person 2 putting in: "))
        P3 = int(input("How much £ is person 3 putting in: "))
        P4 = int(input("How much £ is person 4 putting in: "))
        P1_Gs = P1 / PPG  
        print("Person 1 should get",P1_Gs,)
        P2_Gs = P2 / PPG  
        print("Person 2 should get",P2_Gs,)
        P3_Gs = P3 / PPG  
        print("Person 3 should get",P3_Gs,)
        P4_Gs = P4 / PPG  
        print("Person 4 should get",P4_Gs,)
    elif GroupNo == 3:
        P1 = int(input("How much £ is person 1 putting in: "))
        P2 = int(input("How much £ is person 2 putting in: "))
        P3 = int(input("How much £ is person 3 putting in: "))
        P1_Gs = P1 / PPG  
        print("Person 1 should get",P1_Gs,)
        P2_Gs = P2 / PPG  
        print("Person 2 should get",P2_Gs,)
        P3_Gs = P3 / PPG  
        print("Person 3 should get",P3_Gs,)
    elif GroupNo == 2:
        P1 = float(input("How much £ is person 1 putting in: "))
        P2 = float(input("How much £ is person 2 putting in: "))
        P1_Gs = P1 / PPG 
        print("Person 1 should get",P1_Gs,)
        P2_Gs = P2 / PPG 
        print("Person 2 should get",P2_Gs,)
    elif GroupNo == 1:
        print("It only you, why are you using this ?")
    elif GroupNo > 6:
        print("Too many man, Please try a number below 7")


    

MainCalc()     ```
````

Comment: Learn about loops & dictionaries.

Comment: If the repetition is "unnecessary," why are you doing it?

Comment: @ScottHunter I know theres a better way **scott**, but thats the way i did it to get it too work.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code review questions belong to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. The main technique you need to look into is `for loops`. It can be done in other ways, but this one is pretty straight forward and easy to comprehend:

```py
GroupNo = int(input("How many people are buying?: "))
Gs = float(input("How many grams are you picking up?: "))
Ps = float(input("How much money is being paid?: "))
PPG = Ps / Gs
print ("Price per gram is:" ,"£",PPG,)

def MainCalc():
    if GroupNo == 1:
        print("It's only you, why are you using this?")
    elif GroupNo < 7:
        allMoney = []
        for i in range(GroupNo):        
            allMoney.append(int(input(f"How much £ is person {i+1} putting in: ")))
        for person, money in enumerate(allMoney):
            print(f"Person {person+1} should get: {money/PPG}")  
    else:
        print("Too many people")
    
MainCalc()
```

Output:

```
How many people are buying?: 5
How many grams are you picking up?: 6
How much money is being paid?: 7
Price per gram is: £ 1.1666666666666667
How much £ is person 1 putting in: 8
How much £ is person 2 putting in: 3
How much £ is person 3 putting in: 5
How much £ is person 4 putting in: 4
How much £ is person 5 putting in: 1
Person 1 should get: 6.857142857142857
Person 2 should get: 2.571428571428571
Person 3 should get: 4.285714285714286
Person 4 should get: 3.4285714285714284
Person 5 should get: 0.8571428571428571
```

Answer (score 0):

You can study this code to understand a bit about loops:

```
PPG = 20.34   # Or whatever the proce per gram is.

while True:
    payment = float(input("Enter amount offered: "))
    if payment == 0:  # Quit when the amount is zero
        break
    print('you paid: £',  payment, 'so you get:', payment/PPG, 'grams')
```